# Mariadb INSERT INTO but without ID

Tags: python, sql, mariadb

I want to add data to my database through python, but I do not know what to do with the ID colum.
I have four colums and I only want to add the last three, the ID is counting up itself.

```
def add_data(temp, hum):
try:
    dt = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0).isoformat(' ')
    statement = "INSERT INTO messstation (?id?,uhrzeit, luftfeuchtigkeit, raumtemperatur) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"
    data = (?id?, dt, hum, temp)
    cursor.execute(statement, data)
    connection.commit()
except database.error as e:
    print(f"Error:{e}")
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO messstation (uhrzeit, ...`

Answer (score 0):

This should work if the `id` field is an auto-increment one:

```
statement = "INSERT INTO messstation (uhrzeit, luftfeuchtigkeit, raumtemperatur) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
data = (dt, hum, temp)
```